# Airflow Dag Folder - How to ignore notebook checkpoints

Tags: jupyter-notebook, airflow

Airflow is being too clever and trying to pick up dags within the jupyter notebook checkpoints folder "dags/.ipynb_checkpoints/" which is throwing an error.

Is there a way to config airflow to ignore folders of a certain pattern? like I would .gitignore?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can create `.airflowignore` in `dags` folder:

```
.ipynb_checkpoints
```

From the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#airflowignore):

A `.airflowignore` file specifies the directories or files in DAG_FOLDER that Airflow should intentionally ignore. Each line in `.airflowignore` specifies a regular expression pattern, and directories or files whose names (not DAG id) match any of the patterns would be ignored (under the hood, `re.findall()` is used to match the pattern). Overall it works like a `.gitignore` file.

`.airflowignore` file should be put in your DAG_FOLDER. For example, you can prepare a `.airflowignore` file with contents

```
project_a
tenant_[\d]
```

Then files like `project_a_dag_1.py`, `TESTING_project_a.py`, `tenant_1.py`, `project_a/dag_1.py`, and `tenant_1/dag_1.py` in your DAG_FOLDER would be ignored (If a directory’s name matches any of the patterns, this directory and all its subfolders would not be scanned by Airflow at all. This improves efficiency of DAG finding).

The scope of a `.airflowignore` file is the directory it is in plus all its subfolders. You can also prepare `.airflowignore` file for a subfolder in DAG_FOLDER and it would only be applicable for that subfolder.

Comment: Note: Airflowignore feature is available starting with Airflow 1.10.

Answer (score 5):

Place a file named `.airflowignore` in the directory you want Airflow to ignore.